# Vaadin Removing Vertical Split Panel to "Regular Panel?"

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

I have a tabsheet within a vertical split panel, however I am having a hard time trying to convert the tabsheet so that the vertical split panel is gone and the page just displays the tabsheet.  The tabsheet extends panel and I just want to get rid of the vertical split from the main class.

In my main class i have

```
private void setMainComponent(Component TabWindow) {
    verticalSplit.setFirstComponent(TabWindow);
//can't I just do a panel.setFirstComponent(TabWindow)?
}
```

Is there another way to call up the TabWindow to display just by itself?

Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about a vaadin ui tabsheet?  what class is your "main class"?

Comment: yes I am talking about a vaadin ui tabsheet. Not sure what you mean,but its my main java application class. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: a screenshot and more sourcecode might be useful in this case for better understanding

Comment: panel.setContent(TabWindow)? setFirstComponent is specific to SplitPanels. Use setContent or setComponent. Also I'm not sure what "main class" means.

Comment: riddy thanks that was it, what i meant was that the "main class" built the layout and I had a separate tabsheet class that was supposed to be called by the "main class".  Thanks everyone!